# How to Change Email Logo in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, logo

I'm trying change the default magento logo in email template from Admin Panel, **Content > Design > Configuration** but it doesn't Update on the email. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Design Configuration

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Goto `Content->Configuration->Click on Edit of first Row->Goto Transactional Email->Logo`

[image]

Comment: This is correct solution. Go for it. Let us know if it does not work.

Comment: I have already tried this didn't work out. Image doesn't show after the upload !

Comment: Hello  @AmalMadawa  Please put your image in /magentoRoot/app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Email/web/logo_email.png

Comment: i think cache issue so please clear cache browser and magento backend.

Comment: Magento 2.2 below version has the bug for the email logo upload.the uploaded logo cant create direcory so that images not shown.Please refer to Change File and email upload logo working fine.https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/23103c03c527fe1ed3e1a3be691436818b7963fe

Comment: No this is not magento bug , If you are using above version from magento  2.1.3 then it should work smoothly. Can you please let me know if  your site password protected with htaccess?

Comment: @Sharma no its not

Comment: Which version you are using ? and please update screen shot of page  by visting: CONTENT->Configuration. I will try to sort out your issue

Comment: @Sharma its 2.1.2. new screen shot added

Comment: Oh man, I mentioned in my version comment that LOGO BUG is not if your version is above 2.1.3 but you are using 2.1.3.

Comment: Anyway, Please add "Transactional Email logo" in all of 5 theme. Flush the cache and post back if it doesnt work. =====  In that case, Its magento bug I will have to post complete answer to fix that bug. You issue will be sorted out :) Update back

Answer (score 1):

1-On the Admin sidebar, Content > Design > Configuration > Select your current theme > .

You can see the existing design configuration on the management table, then click on Edit under Action.

2-On the workplace, please scroll down to Other Settings, open Transactional Email setion.

3-To change your Logo Email, click on Upload to choose one of the image files you want to aplly for your logo.

4-Enter the alternate text identify the Logo Image Alt.
You can give the height and width of logo.
Save configuration and changes will reflect.

Answer (score 1):

As @Moin Malek answered the first way to go for people with less programming experience is uploading the specific email logo over the GUI backend.

For people with more programming and especially frontend developing experience, the way to go is like the following:

In `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Email/web` please add a file called `logo_email.png`.

Explanation: 
In `vendor/magento/module_email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php` there is a constant defined like `const DEFAULT_LOGO_FILE_ID = 'Magento_Email::logo_email.png';` which represents the correct named logo file.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the folder permissions were off so magento could not create the folder at /pub/media/email/logo/stores/1

I just manually created that path, and adding my image.

Answer (score 0):

Reference source: https://magentip.com/change-magento-2-store-logo/

You can upload and overwrite the file in logo file path, for example

```
/frontend/Magento/luma/pl_PL/images/logo.svg
```

If you want to Change magento 2 logo programmatically, go to `\app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`
Add this code

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <action method="setLogoFile">
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">
                    images/yournewlogo.png
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Replace `images/yournewlogo.png` with your file path